Второй дисплей весов
Можно ли такое сделать на PowerShell.
Есть весы Vibra, подключаются к компьютеру через переходник COM-потр - USB. К компьютеру подключен второй дисплей (разрешение 960*320). Можно ли через PowerShell:

Получать данные от весов
Открыть отдельное окно на весь экран (на второй дисплей) и показывать информацию от весов
Скрыть работы скрипта с системный трей

Дизайн окна:


На .Net можно. Он используется и в PowerShell. Но на WinForms намного проще.


Можно; 2) можно; 3) нельзя.


@rotabor ну, почему, вроде можно - если запустить powershell из самого себя через wscript, по крайней мере, мы так делали при парсинге данных с хроматографа.

@ViktorTomilov Тогда поделитесь опытом.

@rotabor К сожалению, в комментарии это сложно описать. Я создам ответ. Если что, его можно и стереть затем :)

@ViktorTomilov ??? Я не возражаю

@rotabor Готово

Что касается скрытия в трее. Если я правильно помню, то консольная программа не может спрятать сама себя. Значит, нужно сделать это через неконсольную программу, например, через сервер сценариев.
Создаем скрипт, назовем его "K:\Scripts\hiddenrun.js" (jscript!)
var wsc = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wsc.Run('%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe ' + 
    '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "K:\\Scripts\\Vesy.ps1"', 0, false);

Теперь нам нужно только выполнить:
wscript "K:\Scripts\hiddenrun.js"

